# Error: `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not an S3 object with class Date

Tags: r, ggplot2

I tried to create a stacked bar plot in R, but unfortunately I have several problems. R gives me the following error:

> Error: `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by
>   `fortify()`, not an S3 object with class Date

I searched for a while, but I can't find a solution. Thank you for helping.

```
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 
input <- "C:\\Users\\CPOD1_time.csv" CPOD1_time <- read.csv(input, sep=";") 

CPOD1_time = as.Date(CPOD1_time$date, format = "%d.%m.%Y")
library(lubridate) 

library(ggplot2) 

p<- ggplot(CPOD1_time, aes(x=date, y=number, fill=time)) + 

geom_bar(stat="identity") +theme_bw() + geom_text(aes(y=number), vjust=1.6,

size=3.5) 

print(p)
    dput(CPOD1_time)
    structure(c(17742, 17743, 17744, 17745, 17746, 17747, 17748, 
    17749, 17750, 17751, 17752, 17753, 17754, 17755, 17756, 17757, 
    17758, 17759, 17760, 17761, 17762, 17763, 17764, 17765, 17766, 
    17767, 17768, 17769, 17770, 17771, 17772, 17773, 17774, 17775, 
    17776, 17742, 17743, 17744, 17745, 17746, 17747, 17748, 17749, 
    17750, 17751, 17752, 17753, 17754, 17755, 17756, 17757, 17758, 
    17759, 17760, 17761, 17762, 17763, 17764, 17765, 17766, 17767, 
    17768, 17769, 17770, 17771, 17772, 17773, 17774, 17775, 17776, 
    17742, 17743, 17744, 17745, 17746, 17747, 17748, 17749, 17750, 
    17751, 17752, 17753, 17754, 17755, 17756, 17757, 17758, 17759, 
    17760, 17761, 17762, 17763, 17764, 17765, 17766, 17767, 17768, 
    17769, 17770, 17771, 17772, 17773, 17774, 17775, 17776, 17742, 
    17743, 17744, 17745, 17746, 17747, 17748, 17749, 17750, 17751, 
    17752, 17753, 17754, 17755, 17756, 17757, 17758, 17759, 17760, 
    17761, 17762, 17763, 17764, 17765, 17766, 17767, 17768, 17769, 
    17770, 17771, 17772, 17773, 17774, 17775, 17776), class = "Date")

 as.data.frame(CPOD1_time)

          date time      number
1   30.07.2018    1  0.00000000
2   31.07.2018    1  0.00000000
3   01.08.2018    1  0.00000000
4   02.08.2018    1  0.62500000
5   03.08.2018    1  0.00000000
6   04.08.2018    1  0.00000000
7   05.08.2018    1  0.00000000
8   06.08.2018    1  3.26086957
9   07.08.2018    1  0.00000000
10  08.08.2018    1  0.00000000
11  09.08.2018    1  0.00000000
12  10.08.2018    1  0.00000000
13  11.08.2018    1  0.00000000
14  12.08.2018    1  0.00000000
15  13.08.2018    1  0.00000000
16  14.08.2018    1  0.00000000
17  15.08.2018    1  0.69767442
18  16.08.2018    1  0.00000000
19  17.08.2018    1  0.00000000
20  18.08.2018    1  0.71428571
21  19.08.2018    1  0.71428571
22  20.08.2018    1  0.71428571
23  21.08.2018    1  0.71428571
24  22.08.2018    1  0.00000000
25  23.08.2018    1  3.65853658
26  24.08.2018    1  0.50000000
27  25.08.2018    1  3.00751880
28  26.08.2018    1  1.50375940
29  27.08.2018    1  3.00751880
30  28.08.2018    1  3.75939850
31  29.08.2018    1  0.00000000
32  30.08.2018    1  1.53846154
33  31.08.2018    1  7.69230769
34  01.09.2018    1  5.38461539
35  02.09.2018    1  2.30769231
36  30.07.2018    2  0.16064257
37  31.07.2018    2  0.13100437
38  01.08.2018    2  0.26315789
39  02.08.2018    2  0.19823789
40  03.08.2018    2  0.06622517
41  04.08.2018    2  0.00000000
42  05.08.2018    2  0.00000000
43  06.08.2018    2  0.46927374
44  07.08.2018    2  0.26936027
45  08.08.2018    2  0.33821872
46  09.08.2018    2  0.20385051
47  10.08.2018    2  0.06825939
48  11.08.2018    2  0.27366020
49  12.08.2018    2  0.41284404
50  13.08.2018    2  0.13808976
51  14.08.2018    2  0.06936416
52  15.08.2018    2  0.62717770
53  16.08.2018    2  1.19158878
54  17.08.2018    2  0.07033998
55  18.08.2018    2  0.35335689
56  19.08.2018    2  0.14218010
57  20.08.2018    2  0.85714286
58  21.08.2018    2  0.28742515
59  22.08.2018    2  0.79422383
60  23.08.2018    2  2.10399033
61  24.08.2018    2  1.52727273
62  25.08.2018    2  1.90012180
63  26.08.2018    2  2.50000000
64  27.08.2018    2  0.29556650
65  28.08.2018    2  2.82527881
66  29.08.2018    2  2.31631382
67  30.08.2018    2  2.55319149
68  31.08.2018    2  2.41813602
69  01.09.2018    2  2.05063291
70  02.09.2018    2  2.57309942
71  30.07.2018    3  0.00000000
72  31.07.2018    3  0.00000000
73  01.08.2018    3  0.00000000
74  02.08.2018    3  0.00000000
75  03.08.2018    3  0.00000000
76  04.08.2018    3  0.00000000
77  05.08.2018    3  0.00000000
78  06.08.2018    3  0.00000000
79  07.08.2018    3  0.00000000
80  08.08.2018    3  0.00000000
81  09.08.2018    3  0.66666667
82  10.08.2018    3  0.00000000
83  11.08.2018    3  0.00000000
84  12.08.2018    3  4.13793103
85  13.08.2018    3  0.00000000
86  14.08.2018    3  0.00000000
87  15.08.2018    3  0.71428571
88  16.08.2018    3  2.79069767
89  17.08.2018    3  0.00000000
90  18.08.2018    3  0.00000000
91  19.08.2018    3  0.00000000
92  20.08.2018    3  0.00000000
93  21.08.2018    3  0.72289157
94  22.08.2018    3  0.00000000
95  23.08.2018    3  0.00000000
96  24.08.2018    3  0.00000000
97  25.08.2018    3  0.00000000
98  26.08.2018    3  0.00000000
99  27.08.2018    3  0.00000000
100 28.08.2018    3  0.00000000
101 29.08.2018    3  0.00000000
102 30.08.2018    3  9.23076923
103 31.08.2018    3  0.00000000
104 01.09.2018    3  2.30769231
105 02.09.2018    3  0.00000000
106 30.07.2018    4  0.00000000
107 31.07.2018    4  0.17964072
108 01.08.2018    4  0.17647059
109 02.08.2018    4  0.00000000
110 03.08.2018    4  0.00000000
111 04.08.2018    4  0.00000000
112 05.08.2018    4  0.00000000
113 06.08.2018    4  0.00000000
114 07.08.2018    4  0.32432432
115 08.08.2018    4  0.00000000
116 09.08.2018    4  0.00000000
117 10.08.2018    4  0.31168831
118 11.08.2018    4  1.54241645
119 12.08.2018    4  0.75757576
120 13.08.2018    4 11.89066059
121 14.08.2018    4  1.03703704
122 15.08.2018    4  7.73722628
123 16.08.2018    4  8.09638554
124 17.08.2018    4  1.56769596
125 18.08.2018    4  1.27058823
126 19.08.2018    4  0.55813954
127 20.08.2018    4  0.27522936
128 21.08.2018    4  0.68181818
129 22.08.2018    4  1.88340807
130 23.08.2018    4  2.78761062
131 24.08.2018    4  1.71428571
132 25.08.2018    4  0.39045553
133 26.08.2018    4  0.25751073
134 27.08.2018    4  0.25531915
135 28.08.2018    4  0.25263158
136 29.08.2018    4  0.24896266
137 30.08.2018    4  0.36960986
138 31.08.2018    4  1.09979633
139 01.09.2018    4  0.48387097
140 02.09.2018    4  0.00000000
```

Comment: Can u show the code?

Comment: Your data is a vector, you have to put it into a data.frame

Comment: My code is: options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

input <- "C:\\Users\\CPOD1_time.csv"

CPOD1_time <- read.csv(input, sep=";")

CPOD1_time = as.Date(CPOD1_time$date, format = "%d.%m.%Y")
head(CPOD1_time)
dput(CPOD1_time)
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)
p<- ggplot(CPOD1_time, aes(x=date, y=number, fill=time)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +theme_bw() +
  geom_text(aes(y=number), vjust=1.6, size=3.5)
print(p)

Comment: @Dolphin94  Please update it in your post by `edit`ing.  `ggplot` takes a `data.frame/tbl_df/data.table` object.  Based on the `dput`, it is just a vector, while in the `aes`, you have specified, `x`, `y`, and `fill`.  So, not clear

Comment: @akrun: When I did dput in R, it is not how my data looks in my excel sheet. In my excel sheet, I have 3 rows: date, time, number. How can I change my data from a vector to a data frame?

Comment: csv file is missing...You need to add the "CPOD1_time.csv" file.

Comment: It is confusing when you say that there are 3 rows in excel sheett

Comment: I add the csv file, but I still have this error. Sorry, I  have 3 columns in my excel sheet, not rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:
Workflow is as follows:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
#`df` is `CPOD_Time` saved as `df<-as.data.frame(CPOD_Time)`
df <- as.data.frame(CPOD_Time)
```

Then the plot:

```r
df %>% 
  rename(Time=time,Number=number,Date=date) %>% 
  mutate(Date=str_replace_all(Date,"\\D","-"),Date=as.character(Date),
         Date=dmy(Date)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Date, y=Number, fill=Time)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +theme_bw() + 
  geom_text(aes(label=Number), vjust=1.6,size=3.5)
```

Comment: If I tried this, R gives me the error: Error: `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not an S3 object with class uneval
Did you accidentally pass `aes()` to the `data` argument? I tried ggplot(df(aes(x=Date, y=Number, fill=Time))), but this is not working. And R gives me also the error: could not find function "%>%"

Comment: Load the libraries `tidyverse` and `lubridate`. Plus. Use After saving, you can simply use the last part of this answer. Save like `df<-as.data.frame(yourdata)`. In your code above(in this comment), you miss a comma after `df` in the `ggplot` call. I prefer using the `pipe` but maybe you prefer `ggplot(df,aes(Date,Number,fill=Time))...`

Comment: I loaded the library lubridate. I installed the package tidyverse and loaded it as a library, but I got the error: Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package with the name ‘glue’

Comment: I don't understand how the name `glue` comes up. Use `install.packages("tidyverse",dependencies=T)`. EDIT: glue is in fact a package. Just install as stated in the previous sentence.

Comment: Alternatively, you can load `tidyr`,`dplyr` or `dpylr'(not sure about the spelling),`ggplot2`, `lubridate` and `stringr`

Comment: I loaded the packages tidyr and dplyr. This is working and I don't have any more the error could not find function "%>%" . Thank you very much for this. But it gives me the new error: Error in .f(.x[[i]], ...) : object 'number' not found and Error in .f(.x[[i]], ...) : object 'Date' not found. I wrote like you did: df %>% 
      rename(Time=time,Number=number,Date=date) . In my excel sheet date, time, number are in a small letter.

Comment: Hi, please make sure that  df is infact your `CPOD_Time`. Also try simply copying and pasting the code in the answer with the `stringr` package loaded too. I tested this code using the `dput` you provided. Try `df<-and place the output of dput(CPOD_Time) here`

Comment: Now it is working perfectly. Thank you a lot for all the work. I had a mistake with the small and capital letters.

Comment: Cheers! Glad it helped!