# Error: Data is a dataframe but R gives an error

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, error-handling

I try to make a ggplot for a specific variable. When I use this code it wont work but when I use the same function for a different variable, it works...:

```
waardevol <- ggplot(data=etadam, aes(x = waardevol)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)), colour = "black", width = 0.6, fill = '#ffd308') + geom_text(aes(y = ((..count..)/sum(..count..)), label = scales::percent((..count..)/sum(..count..))), stat = "count", vjust = -0,25) + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent) + 
  labs(y = 'percentage', title = 'Vonden jullie de training waardevol?', subtitle = 'N = 400', caption = 'Leren voor de Toekomst©') 


Data (etadam):
 ID                tijd                       gevoel waardevol        vak niveau vertrouwen
1 90 2021-04-25 15:16:11        Vrolijk;Gemotiveerd ;        Ja     Engels   HAVO         Ja
2 91 2021-04-25 15:17:08 Relaxt;Gemotiveerd ;Vrolijk;        Ja     Engels   HAVO         Ja
3 92 2021-04-25 15:49:16                    Neutraal;        Ja Wiskunde A   HAVO         Ja
4 93 2021-04-25 15:49:00              Trots;Gezegend;        Ja Wiskunde A   HAVO         Ja
5 94 2021-04-25 15:49:03                    Neutraal;        Ja Wiskunde A   HAVO        Nee
6 95 2021-04-25 15:49:23                    Neutraal;        Ja Wiskunde A   HAVO         Ja
uitleg                                       oefenexamen aanraden           vervolgopleiding
1 Zeer goed                                               6.1       Ja                        Nee
2 Zeer goed 4,8 maar ik heb slecht geslapen daar ligt het aan       Ja Bouwkunde HVA architectuur
3 Zeer goed                                               6,5       Ja             Cyber security
4   Normaal                                               5.2       Ja          Ja, verpleegkunde
5 Kan beter                                               5.7      Nee                        Nee
6      Goed                                                 -       Ja                        Nee

This Code acctually did work: 

uitleg <- ggplot(data=etadam, aes(x = uitleg)) + 
    geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)), colour = "black", width = 0.6, fill = '#ffd308') +
    geom_text(aes(y = ((..count..)/sum(..count..)), label = scales::percent((..count..)/sum(..count..))), stat = "count", vjust = 5) + 
    scale_y_continuous(labels = percent) + 
    labs(x = NULL, y = 'percentage', title = 'Wat vonden jullie van de uitleg? - Alle trainingen', subtitle = 'N = 400', caption = 'Leren voor de Toekomst')


After I run the copied the last quote and run it a couple of times, the same error arises.
```

Answer (score 0):

use `class()` function to confirm if they are the same type of variable.

Comment: They are all factors

Comment: Error: `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not a numeric vector

Comment: Hi, it looks like this question is pretty similar to your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54050320/error-data-must-be-a-data-frame-or-other-object-coercible-by-fortify-no. As I don't have your dataset, I'm afraid that I can't replicate your data and codes in my computer. But I believe this shouldn't be a big problem, maybe try again `data <- as.data.frame(data)`. BTW did you load your data via tidyverse?

Comment: Hi there, it is still not working. The weird thing is, is that `is.data.frame(etadam)` turns out to be TRUE. So R recognizes my data as a dataframe but when I try to use ggplot2, the error code is still there....

Comment: I solved the problem. The problem was stated in the vjust where the '-' wasn't the right notation! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Great! Glad to know that, haha neither did I see that small notation.